# MySQL update once WPF DataGrid cell has been edited

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that is generated from a MySQL query. I would like to to be able to edit the database directly by modifying the DataGrid. Basically what I need is to generate a string like this after user has finished editing a cell:

pseudocode:

> "UPDATE current_table SET current_column_name=new_cell_value WHERE id=number that is in the hidden first cell of the edited row"

What would be the most simple way to achieve this?

I've tried looking at the DataGrid properties and events but so far I could not find any "CellEditEnded" events nor can I find how to get the new value or the id that's in the first cell of the row.

EDIT:
Ok, I've made some progress, I am now able to get the id and the column name, but the problem is that I am unable to get the new cell value. I think the problem is that this code fires in CellEditEnding-event, so the change hasn't been commited yet. How can I fix this?

```
DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)gameDatagrid.SelectedItem;
int index = gameDatagrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
string columnName = gameDatagrid.CurrentCell.Column.Header.ToString();
string cellValue = dataRow.Row.ItemArray[index].ToString();
string id = dataRow.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(id + " : " + columnName + " : " + cellValue);
```

Comment: take a look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e71304ed-22b1-4882-9f5c-d9e42ad97445/how-to-get-new-value-in-a-datagrid-cell-after-editing-cell?forum=wpf

Comment: Everything works like a charm now, thanks Jossef!

Comment: Fo-shizzle my nizzle :) post an answer to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a helpful comment I was able to solve this. The full code is as follows:

```
    private void gameDatagrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
        DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)gameDatagrid.SelectedItem;
        int index = gameDatagrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
        string columnName = gameDatagrid.CurrentCell.Column.Header.ToString();
        string newValue = t.Text;
        int id = (int)dataRow.Row.ItemArray[0];
        string query = "UPDATE table_name SET " + columnName + "=\"" + newValue + "\" WHERE id=" + id;
    }
```